# Non-transparent background when widgets are overlapped

Tags: flutter

I want to build a widget like group box with a title:
[image]

How could I make a line behind "Options" word invisible?

Here is my code:

```
 return Stack(
      children: [
        const Positioned(
          left: 40,
          top: 0,
          child: Text(
            'Options',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(30, 32, 32, 32),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
               border: Border.all(
                         width: 2.0,
                         color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                       ),
            ),
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 800),
           // ... the rest of controls
        ),
      ],
    );
```

I tried to wrap a title with different widgets with `backgroundColor` property, but without success. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried different colors i.e. `Colors.black` - no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write 'option' text component after the Container component so that 'option' text component will be over the container.
And use black color (same as the scaffold color).

```html
Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 2.0,
                        color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      ),
                    ),
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 800),
                    // ... the rest of controls
                  ),
                ),
                const Positioned(
                  left: 40,
                  top: 0,
                  child: Text(
                    'Options',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black //same as scaffold background color
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```